# Raphael.js how to find degrees between coordinates of last click and mouse current position?

Tags: javascript, raphael

When I click on `paper` I store the position in `lastX` and `lastY` values:

```
lastX = e.screenX;
lastY = e.screenY;
```

On mousemove I update the `currentX` and `currentY` values:

```
currentX = e.screenX;
currentY = e.screenY;
```

Can I determine somehow what is the degree between this two coordinates? I think the x line is the 0 degree. But here stopped my science.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the origin is the point `(lastX, lastY)`, and zero degrees is the positive x-axis, 
the degree to the point `(currentX, currentY)` would be:

```
function degreesToPoint(origin, endP){
    if(typeof origin != typeof [] or typeof endP != typeof [])
        return false;
    else {
        var slope = {
            x: origin[0] - endP[0],
            y: origin[1] - endP[1]
        };
        var degrees = Math.atan(slope.y / slope.x) * 180 / Math.PI;
        if(slope.x < 0 && slope.y >= 0){
            degrees += 180;
        } else if (slope.x < 0 && slope.y < 0) {
            degrees -= 180;
        }
        return degrees;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some other google searches:

```
var radian = Math.atan((currentY-lastY)/(currentX-lastX));
var degree = radian * (180/Math.PI);
```

Comment: This won't work if the current point is to the right of the point